# Change IP as user with powershell script on Win 7

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-7-embedded

On my Windows 7 Embedded machine I want to change the IP address via Powershell script as an user.

For that I added my user to the "Network Configuration Operators" group and wrote the following script.

```
param(
[string]$Type
)

Write-Host "Networkchanger"

$adapter = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "Index = 11"

if($Type -eq "black"){
    Write-Host "Using black"
    $IP = "192.168.1.172"
    $Netmask = "255.255.255.0"
    $Gateway = "192.168.1.1"
    $DNS = "192.168.1.254"
    $adapter.EnableStatic($IP, $NetMask)
    Sleep -Seconds 4
    $adapter.SetGateways($Gateway)
    $adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNS)
} else {
    Write-Host "Using rf"
    $adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder()
    $adapter.EnableDHCP()
}
```

The script runs fine as admin, but not as an user. Did I forget to add some rights to the script or user?

**Edit:**
When I click "Run as admin" and use *black* it works for the first time. After changing it to *rf* (which works), the *black* net just changes the Gateway and DNS, but not the IP and Netmask, which confuses me.

Comment: What happens when you run as user? Do you get an error message? Add `Write-Host $adapter` - is this blank for user?

Comment: I can see the adapter as user und running it as admit works partly... (see my edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by heavily modifing my Powershell script:

```
$id=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$principal=New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($id)
if(!$principal.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
$powershell=[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()
$psi=New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $powershell.Path
$script=$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$prm=$script+$Type
foreach($a in $args) {
  $prm+=' '+$a
}
$psi.Arguments=$prm
$psi.Verb="runas"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi) | Out-Null
return;
}

Write-Host "Networkchanger"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "[0] cancel"
Write-Host "[1] net1:    10.0.0.172"
Write-Host "[2] net2:    192.168.178.(172,235,237,248,251)"

$adapter = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "Index = 0"
$loop = 1;

while($loop -eq 1){
    $Type = Read-Host -Prompt '0, 1 OR 2'
    switch($Type){
        0 {
            Write-Host "Cancel Process"
            Sleep -Seconds 3
            exit
        }
        1 {
            Write-Host "Using sb"
            $IP = "10.0.0.172"
            $Netmask = "255.255.255.0"
            $Gateway = "10.0.0.1"
            $DNS = "10.0.0.254"
            $adapter.EnableStatic($IP, $NetMask)
            Sleep -Seconds 4
            $adapter.SetGateways($Gateway)
            $adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNS)
            $loop = 0
        }
        2 {
            Write-Host "Using rf"
            $macaddress = $adapter | select -expand macaddress
            Write-Host $macaddress
            $IP = ""
            if ($macaddress -eq "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"){
                $IP = "192.168.178.172"
            } elseif ($macaddress -eq "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx") {
                $IP = "192.168.178.235"
            } elseif ($macaddress -eq "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx") {
                $IP = "192.168.178.237"
            } elseif ($macaddress -eq "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx") {
                $IP = "192.168.178.248"
            } elseif ($macaddress -eq "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx") {
                $IP = "192.168.178.251"
            } else {
                Write-Host "Mac address not in list"
                Sleep -Seconds 5
                exit
            }
            $Netmask = "255.255.255.0"
            $Gateway = "192.168.178.1"
            $DNS = "192.168.178.2","192.168.178.3"
            $adapter.EnableStatic($IP, $NetMask)
            Sleep -Seconds 4
            $adapter.SetGateways($Gateway)
            $adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNS)
            $loop = 0
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Current IP: "
ipconfig

Start-Sleep -seconds 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that admin rights are required for setting a static IP address.  I do it on our Windows Embedded Standard 7 images.  Essentially, I created a shortcut on the desktop with Run As Administrator for launching PowerShell with the particular script. Also note that no such elevated permission is required to enable DHCP, but it doesn't hurt.

There is a slightly simpler way to set the IP address from PowerShell, using the netsh command.  The good thing about this approach is that you can see the specific error from a command prompt also.  Try switching back and forth from an elevated command prompt and a non-elevated one.

```
netsh interface ip set address "${InterfaceName}" static addr=${IPAddr}  mask=${Mask} gateway=${Gateway}
netsh interface ip set address "${InterfaceName}" dhcp
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it worked fine as admin, but got to a point where I had the same right difficulties. I've now resolved to problem with Powershell. But thank you for your efford.